# How to remove NgForm field after form submission

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to know if it is possible to remove a form field from a submitted NgForm function.

I am using a plugin for ionic 3 called Select-Searchable that these two form fields are using. The plugin requires the arrays to be set up as so, so it works properly.

I have this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ToastController,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SelectSearchableComponent } from 'ionic-select-searchable';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { ReapService } from '../../services/reap-service';
import { ProjectReviewPage } from '../project-review/project-review';

class Location {
  public ID: number;
  public Location: string;
}
class updatedLocation {
  public ID: number;
  public Location: string;
}
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-project',
  templateUrl: 'project.html',
})
export class ProjectPage {
 private locationsArray: Location[];
 location: Location;
 private updatedLocation: updatedLocation[];
 updatedlocation: updatedLocation; 
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
             public navParams: NavParams,
             public reap: ReapService,
             public toastCtrl: ToastController,
             private geolocation: Geolocation,
             private platform: Platform) {
             
             this.locationsArray = reap.getLocations;
             this.updatedLocation = [];
             }
             
             
   grabLocation(){
        this.selectedClosestLoc = true;
        /* Ensure the platform is ready */
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        /* Grabs user geolocation */
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            // 4 decimal places
            this.userLocation = [parseFloat(resp.coords.latitude.toFixed(4)),parseFloat(resp.coords.longitude.toFixed(4))];
           
            this.userLocation = [resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude];
            //var t0 = performance.now();
            //Calls service to handle location 
            this.reap.grabUserLoc(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
            //var t1 = performance.now();
            //console.log("Call to grabUserLoc took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
            this.updatedLocation = this.reap.updatedLocation;

            console.log(this.updatedLocation);
          }).catch((error) => {
            //console.log('Error getting location', error);
            this.presentToast(error);
          });
        });
      }          
             
onSubmit(Form: NgForm){
    if(!Form.value.Location){//If user grabs nearest location
      Form.value.Location = Form.value.updatedLocation;//update form value
      //console.log(Form.value.Location);
      Form.value.remove.updatedLocation//Some type of remove option for the form
     }
    }
     searchableChange(event: { component: SelectSearchableComponent, value: any         }) {
        console.log('value:', event.value);
    } 
    resetLocation(){
          this.wellLocation = [];
          this.updatedLocation = [];
          this.selectedClosestLoc = false;
      }
  }
```

To make things a little more clear, I have a `*ngIf` statement determined by a button the user clicks to switch between two different form fields. The fields ultimately store the same end value, but of course I have them set as two different values and for my API I feel like it would be more convenient to keep one value.

HTML code: Just showing the two form fields that are in the question for simplicity.The data from Location is from my API and the updatedLocation filters through the data based on the users location via gps coordinates.

```html
 <ion-content>
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
   <ion-list>  
    <ion-item class="formField ionField" *ngIf="!selectedClosestLoc">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked >LOCATION</ion-label>
          <select-searchable
          item-content
          [(ngModel)]="location"
          [items]="locationsArray"
          title="Location"
          itemValueField=ID
          itemTextField=Location
          name="Location"
          [canSearch]="true"
          [canClear]="true"
          (onChange)="searchableChange($event)">
        </select-searchable>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="formField ionField" *ngIf="selectedClosestLoc">
      <!-- data thrown into dropdown from API -->
      <ion-label stacked>NEAREST LOCATION</ion-label>
        <select-searchable
         item-content
         ngModel
         title="updatedLocation"
         itemValueField=ID
         itemTextField=Location
         name="updatedLocation"
         [items]="updatedLocation"
         [canSearch]="true"
         [canClear]="true"
         [focusSearchbar]="true"
         (onChange)="searchableChange($event)">
       </select-searchable>
    </ion-item>

     <ion-item>
        <button [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit" id="submitButton" ion-button            full large>Submit</button>
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: perhaps you need to share more of your code. It's hard to see what you are trying to do without.

Comment: @mix3d I can show my html code if you need that? But only the fields regarding my question if that would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

```
delete Form.value['updatedLocation'];
```

Unless I misunderstood the original question, you are just concerned with what is being sent to API, not the Angular form anymore.  So we just need to remove a property from a javascript object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21033426)

Comment: I think this is a possible solution for what the author originally asked.

Comment: can you elaborate on this answer? Or any documentation on this perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

```
Form.reset(); or Form.SetValue(""); or if validators Form.markAsUntouched();
```

or if you are trying to remove a formcontrol from the formgroup you can use

```
 .removeControl();
```

more info here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Comment: I don't want to reset the other values on the form nor do I want to reset the form field. My goal is to remove that particular form field completely.

Comment: your question states you want to remove a form value from a submitted NGform, that would be either reset or setting the value to something empty. You can reset the value on only a single form control.

Comment: OK, I'll try again. You have two form fields that switch out between each other based on a button but you only want to pass one to your API right?,

If location is false (or maybe empty?)
you want to use the data in UpdatedLocation?

Comment: Correct, so after The form submits I set the value of the updatedLocation to Location and that works fine. Now all I want to do is remove the updatedLocation form field completely from the form.

Comment: Are you submitting the entire form to the api and just want to remove a single FormControl? Could you not just simply not pass the data to the api and forget it then? If that will not work would you mind supplying more information on your .ts file for a more clear picture of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am submitting the whole form and yes I could technically skip the form field, but I was wanting to know if there is a possibility to remove the form field here without having to worry about another form field. I will update the question with more info.